# Firebase Function: Type Error: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to build a Chatting on android as Lapit Chat I am writing this  node.js script and deployed it:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {


  const user_id = change.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = change.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);


  if (!change.after.val()) {
return console.log('A notification has been deleted from database: ', notification_id);
 }


  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

    console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);



    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

      const userName = result[0].val();
      const token_id = result[1].val();


      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
          icon: "default",
          click_action : "com.example.ragha.safeheartchatting_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        },
        data : {
          from_user_id : from_user_id
        }
      };



      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        return console.log('This was the notification Feature');

      });

    });

  });

});
```

After running the application and send a requeston firebase cloud i got an error and it appears in the firebase database but not appear in the mobile android

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:12:31)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:768:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values of the wildcard, use `context`, not `change`.  `change` just describes what changed in the database that triggered a call to your function.

```
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
```

You should [read the documentation for database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to learn the APIs.

Comment: Thanks very very much